# Split a group of unordered list into divs with jquery after a number of li items

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I need to break group of unordered list contained in a div into columns by inserting a separator

```
</div><div>
```

after current ul or before the next ul.

The new divs will contain different number of lines because li is counted for reference only, but the separator should be inserted between next closing and opening ul only (between unordered lists).

This is what I am trying to achieve:
[jsFiddle (HTML only)](https://jsfiddle.net/jsnoobs/9nkr5yvx/)

```html
    <li>Item four</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- need to insert this with jquery dynamically-->
</div><div>
  <!--jquery insert eof -->
  <ul>
    <li>Item five</li>
```

What I tried ([jsFiddle jquery](https://jsfiddle.net/jsnoobs/umo550bm/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //why does this not work?
  $('li:eq(3)').parent().before('</div><span>This is a test insert</span><div>');
});
```

```css
div {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
span {
  color: green;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Item one</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Item two</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 2.1</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Item three</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Item four</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Item five
      <ul>
        <li>Item 5.1</li>
        <li>Item 5.2</li>
        <li>Item 5.3</li>
        <li>Item 5.4</li>
        <li>Item 5.5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Item six
      <ul>
        <li>Item 6.1</li>
        <li>Item 6.2</li>
        <li>Item 6.3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Item seven</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Item ten</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Item eleven</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Item twelve</li>
  <ul/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, have you looked at CSS columns? They may do what you want without JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts

---

Your problem is that you first need to understand how HTML is represented internally, the DOM (Document Object Model): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

It is made up of "elements" that can contain elements themselves. You can imagine an element as a box. For example, a `div` element, that (in your case) contains `ul` elements, which in turn contain `li` elements, and so on.

The tags you use in HTML source code are just textual (human readable) representations of these boxes, with the opening tag (`<div>`) being the beginning, and the closing tag (`</div>`) being the end of the element.

Just like in read life where the top of a box or the bottom of a box alone don't make sense and you can't split a box into two by inserting a new "bottom" and "top" into the middle of the box.

Elements are indivisible entities. So a closing tag on it's own doesn't make sense, so you can't insert them like that.

In conclusion: Instead of splitting a `div` you need to create a new `div`, and transfer elements from the original `div` into the new one, and append the new `div` after the old one.

---

Intermezzo: First we need to make sure you are using the right HTML. Your example `div` contains multiple `ul` elements but each only contains only one `li`. However in your example HTML you are spitting between the `ul` elements, but in your JavaScript you are trying to split between `li` elements.

So you have to choose one: Have either

- a `div` filled with `ul` and split between the `ul`s or
- a `ul` filled with `li` and split between the `li`s

In any case, the following code will work independently in both cases.

---

Another unclear thing is: Where exactly do you want to split? Your example HTML there doesn't seem to be any indication where you want to spit the list. In this case I'll use a class to mark the locations for splitting. If you need something else you'll need to explain it better.

---

Back to the problem:

```js
$(".split-me").each(function() {
 var elementType = this.nodeName; // Get the element type ("div", "ul", etc.) so we can create new ones.
  var parent = $(this);
  var previousElement = parent;
  parent.children(".split-here").each(function() {
   // Find all children where we want to split and loop over them.
    var newElement = $("<" + elementType + ">"); // $("<div>") is short for $("<div></div>"). It creates a new "complete" element, not just it's "top", because that's not possible.
    var child = $(this);
    var childrenToMove = child.add(child.nextUntil('.split-here')); // Take the current child, and all it's following siblings until the next split location
    newElement.append(childrenToMove); // Insert them into the new element
    previousElement.after(newElement); // Insert the new element after the previous one
    previousElement = newElement;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="split-me">
  <li>The</li>
  <li>content</li>
  <li>doesn't</li>
  <li>matter.</li>
  <li class="split-here">This</li>
  <li>is</li>
  <li>just</li>
  <li>an</li>
  <Li>example.</Li>
  <li class="split-here">The</li>
  <li>end.</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/smLtrx72/

Comment: thank you I am going to try your solution. I am not using CSS columns because this will be used in a big drop down menu and I need all sub-items be in one block. 

Your example with the box is very clear, by trial and error I realized myself, that an element can not canib

Comment: I realized myself, by trial and error, that an element can not cannibalize itself.

Comment: I realized myself, by trial and error, that an element can not cannibalize itself. 
I am using this weird html because I am working on existing client's site, and the list is generated with php. 

I want to split to make 4 or 5 columns side to side: $(this).find('li').length divided by 5. 

But, because the number of lines per column may match the middle of sub-list, the splitting should happen after the sub-list, which is after closing ul tag. In other words I want to split after number of li, but not earlier than closing ul

Comment: Just a small remark: If you are using PHP to generate this, then you could (should) be using PHP instead of JavaScript to split the list.

Comment: RoToRa I do not agree, I want a flexible and responsive result: i divide the window width by column width to define the number of columns, then I define the number of items in each column dividing $(this).find('li').length by the number of columns. This all is out of php scope.

Comment: I also tried column-count css, it does the job, and display:inline-block solves sub-lists remaining one block with parent item, but it does not look good, needs additional css, and is not compatible with internet explorer. I'd rather rely on jquery